# How do I set a common header component for all my pages in IONIC 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to set a common component as the header in all my ionic pages (Ionic4). What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Just create a component name header and instide the ts file add @Input name then in ion-title add {{name}}; and in any page you need to call this component like <app-header name="toolbar title you need"></app-header>

Comment: I need not want dynamically changing titles, but the same component header for different pages

Answer (score 4):

create a custom component.

Run: `ionic g component header`
command generate a component with this content

```
header.component.html
header.component.scss
header.component.ts
```

Inside header.component.html put your header content, for example:

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title class="ion-text-center">title</ion-title>    
</ion-toolbar>
```

Inside every html page of your app insert:

```
<ion-header>
  <app-header></app-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

Remeber to add **Component's Module** inside **app.module.ts** or **page.module.ts** if using lazy loading

Answer (score 1):

Improving [parrycima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9685038/parrycima) answer:

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
   <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title class="ion-text-center">{{title}}</ion-title>    
</ion-toolbar>
```

So you can change title on every page you import header.

In header.component.ts:

```
@Input() public title: string = "";
```

So title is an input you can pass when you use app-header inside your html page:

```
<app-header title="CurrenPageTitle"></app-header>
```

The best aprouch that works for me is to create the file components.module.ts in src/app with this code:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [HeaderComponent],
    imports: [IonicModule],
    exports: [HeaderComponent]
})
```

Then in app.module.ts:

```
entryComponents: [HeaderComponent],
imports: [
    ....,
    ComponentsModule,
    ...
]
```

On every html page you want to add this custom header you need to add ComponentsModule to imports of yourhtmlpage.modules.ts:

```
imports: [
        ....,
        ComponentsModule,
        ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

On your app.component.html you can add header component like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

Comment: Hi, so I did that. The header appears but the thing is it is overlapping the content of the page

Comment: @xJokerx add on your app.componennt.css main{
    margin:2rem auto;
}